# Way to go around an administrators account to send external email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHP mailer to send emails from a web application and have realized that only when an administrators account is used can the application send emails to external emails.

I am using SMTP. In order to send an email to an external email, the SMTP account needs to be an administrators account.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: What do you mean by Administrator account? are you using SMTP?

Comment: What do you mean by administrators account? (on when the application runs as root, on the application, on the mailserver?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a mail account on that server, it is not necessary that it should be only administrator account, but any mail account of that domain can be used.